LTspice: Troubleshooting a common emitter amplifier
This is a screenshot of a common emitter amplifier my instructor made in LTspice (everything is working fine):

This is my attempt to make the same circuit (it isn't working, there's no amplification and lots of distortion):

I have looked for differences in the circuits for hours now but can't find out why my circuit isn't working eventhough they both seem to be identical.
Any ideas on what parameters I have missed?


This isn't connected in your version of the circuit.

Even when you make that base connection, consider what the voltage is there. With +15 VIN, the junction is 15*5990/(5990+108200) = 0.787 V.
This will barely be able to turn on the transistor (and likely not at all at temperatures of freezing (0 deg C) or lower). This means that the bias setup is not very predictable or consistent, making it a poor design.
Further consider the 33 Ω emitter R. If (say) there was 100 mV across this, the current would be 3 mA. With a beta of 100, this means 30 ua of base current is required -- which drops an additional 3 V across the 108k. Again, the bias setup is not very stable.
